# Issue with dropdown menu not displaying options when formControlName is present

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am facing an issue with a dropdown menu in my Angular application. I have a form with multiple rows, each containing several dropdown menus. However, when the formControlName attribute is present for a dropdown menu, no options are displayed when I click on it. Even the "Results not found" message is not shown.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div formArrayName="rows">
    <div *ngFor="let row of formGroup.get('rows').value; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <p-dropdown [options]="meshTerms" placeholder="PATHOLOGIE" formControlName="meshTermOrSynonym"></p-dropdown>
      <p-dropdown [options]="andOrNothing" formControlName="andOrNothing1"></p-dropdown>
      <p-dropdown [options]="interventionCategories" placeholder="INTERVENTION" formControlName="interventionCategory"></p-dropdown>
      <p-dropdown [options]="andOrNothing" formControlName="andOrNothing2"></p-dropdown>
      <p-dropdown [options]="resultCategories" placeholder="RESULTAT" formControlName="resultCategory"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button (click)="addRow()" label="Ajouter une colonne" pButton type="button"></button>
```

And here is a part of the corresponding component:

```
export class EquationTableComponent implements OnInit {
  rows: FormGroup[] = [];
  meshTerms: string[] = [];
  andOrNothing: string[] = [];
  interventionCategories: string[] = [];
  resultCategories: string[] = [];
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      rows: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.addRow();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.andOrNothing = ['AND', 'OR', 'RIEN'];
  }

  addRow() {
    const row = this.fb.group({
      meshTermOrSynonym: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
      andOrNothing1: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
      interventionCategory: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
      andOrNothing2: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
      resultCategory: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
    });
    this.rows.push(row);
    (this.formGroup.get('rows') as FormArray).push(row);
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm facing a frustrating issue with dropdown menus in Angular with PrimeNG when using form controls. I've tried various approaches, but I can't seem to get the options to display at all when form control is involved, unlike other methods I've tried.